# Custom overlay on Google Map android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I want to be able to draw over a map using Google Maps API -
say, when user clicks "the USA" - the USA should be marked with red, all other countries -become grey
etc.

How do I do this? any ideas?
or should I use something different than Google Maps?

tania

Comment: You can draw a canvas on the coordinates of the selected country

Comment: The tricky part will be to get the coordinates of the countries' border, I dont think the GMaps API has a function for that. 
I'm sure they are available somewhere, in some format. You'd then have to save the borders' coordinates to some file or database to use with the android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates of the countries from Open street map, store them and then draw polygons over the stock google maps.

Comment: but in Open Street Map it is not showing overlay (addTileOverlay) above 7.1.1. version. Is there any solution?